# App crashes when trying to populate a list fragment with volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, android-volley

I am trying to use volley to populate a list fragment with json however the app crashes when I navigate to the fragment.the error is occuring as a result of the mitigation of the previouse error that was changing the values seen below to their respective solutions in the Accommodation fragment.however when i do this it crashes the app.If anyone has an idea as to how I can fix this problem,A solution would be much appreciated.Thanks

```
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
```

to

```
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
```

and

```
 pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

to

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

this is the **AccommodationFragment.java** file

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.accommodation_fragment, container, false);
    //txtFragmentone = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtFragmentOne);
    //txtFragmentone.setText(R.string.fragment_tab_one);
    rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));

    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

    return rootView;
}
```

this is the **CustomListAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        // rating
        rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

        // genre
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and this is my eror logcat

```
   08-29 14:02:23.947  13763-13763/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method b.a
08-29 14:02:23.962  13763-13763/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method b.a
08-29 14:02:24.007  13763-13763/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method b.a
08-29 14:02:24.022  13763-13763/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'ar', referenced from method b.a
08-29 14:02:24.022  13763-13763/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'at', referenced from method b.a
08-29 14:02:24.037  13763-13763/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.RemoteInput[]', referenced from method b.a
08-29 14:02:26.992  12466-12466/br.liveo.navigationviewpagerliveo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.liveo.navigationviewpagerliveo, PID: 12466
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at br.liveo.fragments.AccommodationFragment.onCreateView(AccommodationFragment.java:98)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
```

Comment: try   (adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), movieList);) but i'm not sure if that will work

Comment: Which line is line 98 on "AccommodationFragment"? There is some variable that you haven't properly initialized and is null.

Comment: listView.setAdapter(adapter);   is line 98